# wxPython. How to open a folder with wxWidget (python) hyperlink?

Tags: python, hyperlink, wxpython, directory, wxwidgets

I want to create a hyperlink in my wx widget which opens linked folder on clicking. Please help me how to build that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
os.system("start C:")
```

will launch a file window (on windows at least) ... it has nothing to do with wx

unless you are talking about opening a FilePickerDialog?

I have also been informed that

```
os.system("explorer C:")
```

would also work

Comment: Thanks. That worked for windows. Can you also help me with the OS X version of python statement?

Comment: I cant say for sure as i dont have a mac... but a quick google looks like `os.system("open /path/to/folder")`

Comment: this may really be an XY problem ... what are you actually trying to do (why do you want to open a folder like this?)

Comment: I basically need to add a hyperlink on the file name (in the product, I am trying to make).